# Python: Highlighting exact phrase search results in Whoosh

Tags: python, indexing, full-text-search, whoosh

According to the Whoosh docs (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284758/exact-match-of-multiple-words-in-whoosh) previous question on SO), it's possible to search for an [exact phrase](http://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/querylang.html#individual-terms-and-phrases) in Whoosh by placing double quotes around the phrase for which one wishes to search. When I try to implement an exact phrase search, though, I get back what appear to be the results generated by the default search syntax. Does anyone know how I can alter my search syntax so as to match only those portions of the queried doc (Project Gutenberg's Gulliver's Travels) that contain the exact phrase "government of reason"? I would be grateful for any pointers others can offer.

```
from whoosh.index import create_in
from whoosh.fields import *
from whoosh import qparser
import os, codecs, nltk

def remove_non_ascii(s):
    return "".join(x for x in s if ord(x) < 128)

if not os.path.exists("indexdir"):
    os.mkdir("indexdir")

schema = Schema(content=TEXT(stored=True, analyzer=analysis.StandardAnalyzer(stoplist=None)))

ix = create_in("indexdir", schema)
writer = ix.writer()
gulliver = codecs.open("gulliver.txt","r","utf-8")
gulliver = gulliver.read().replace("_","")
writer.add_document(content=gulliver)
writer.commit()

searcher = ix.searcher()

parser = qparser.QueryParser("content", schema=ix.schema)
q = parser.parse(u"government of reason")
results = searcher.search(q)
results.fragmenter.charlimit = None

for hit in results:
    print " ".join( remove_non_ascii( nltk.clean_html( hit.highlights("content", top=1000000) ) ).split() )
```

### EDIT

Matt Chaput offered some code that should return exact phrases in the hit highlights of a given query in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Whoosh/_bQJ-kk0BFc) short post, but I can't get his method to work.

Comment: Have you tried `'"government of reason"'`?

Comment: Yep, no luck. I tried `'"government of reason"'` both with and without the unicode preface, but no dice.