# highlight search query full result in whoosh

Tags: python, full-text-search, information-retrieval, whoosh

I have a query

```
   t1 = query.Term("content", "field")
   t2 = query.Term("content", "information")
   t3 = query.Term("content", "document")
   q = spans.SpanNear2([t1, t2, t3], slop=5, ordered=True)
```

finds and marks individual words.

> [information] A [field] is a piece [document] create [document] of
> [information] for each [document] in the index,...

but I need to mark whole correct expression. (?)

> information A [**field is a piece document create document of
> information for each document]** in the index,...

Answer (score 0):

There has already been some reasearch on this topic. I haven't personnally tried it but it might be helpful:

- Another SO thread on the matter: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095822/python-highlighting-exact-phrase-search-results-in-whoosh)
- To match a full phrase you can use phrase queries: [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284758/exact-match-of-multiple-words-in-whoosh)
- Apparently some unofficial code has been written regarding this issue: [3](https://groups.google.com/g/Whoosh/c/_bQJ-kk0BFc)

Comment: Please include all the relevant information in the answer, or flag the question as duplicate if it has an answer somewhere else.